Why would I beat you or why will I beat you?
Suppose my friend is telling me that I will beat him but there there's no reason. In that case what will I say in the surprise? "Why would I beat you"  or "Why will I beat you"?

'would' implies "uncertain future" and 'will' implies "certain" future. It depends on your level of perception of the feasibility of beating your friend.

Beat him in a competition, or physically "beat" him in a fight? I know it must be the former, but you didn't say...

If it's a tennis match then he could say "You'll easily beat me" or "There's no way I could possibly win this game" YOUR reply could be: "Why do you think I'm better than you?" OR "Why do you think I'll win?"

I see that Mari-Lou asked the same question I did. A mod must have removed my question. I also asked the OP to show research, of some kind.

Why would I beat you? suggests surprise at the notion that you might in fact administer any beating at all. It can be paraphrased as “What conditions would be sufficient to bring about such an unexpected turn of events as my beating you?”
In contrast, Why will I beat you? can be paraphrased as “Although it is a given that I shall indeed administer a beating, please enumerate the considerations that have led to this state of affairs.”

Worth noting that the second version really just connotes that the friend is certain they will be beaten, not that you necessarily do. The friend states their certainty with the use of "will", and you're asking about that certainty by using the same structure. If I say Alice will give me a million dollars tomorrow, you can ask me why she will do that - you'd be asking about my certainty without implying at all that you actually believe I'm getting $1M tomorrow.

@NuclearHoagie, if it were I who was told, “You will beat me,” then regardless of the speaker’s confidence in their assertion, I would not be nearly so likely to ask, “Why will I beat you?” as, “Why would I beat you?” Or better yet, “Why would I do that?”

I agree, but both options juxtapose the other person's certainty with your skepticism. My point is that neither "will" nor "would" really imply that you are also certain that a beating is imminent - the other person is the only one sure of a beating, it's not really "a given" for everyone.

Ok, I've understood. Suppose someone says to me "I think you hate me" but I don't hate her, there's no reason to hate her. So in that case, being surprised, can I say "Why would I hate you?" ?

Yes, exactly so.


Why would I ever beat you?

You're expressing that  you beating him is not even  a remote possibility.
If your friend has a time-machine and has visited the future, and is telling you that you will indeed beat him before the sun goes down, then you can ask:

Why will I beat you?

You want to know the particulars of the situation.
